# Changing visibility of symbols & objects after compilation in gcc on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, ld, elf

I am trying to rebind the addresses of hidden variable symbols and C++ virtual table objects and export them in a dynamic library. Any help would be appreciated.

**Background**
I am transitioning a large C & C++ project from static compilation to dynamic linking. The product is performance sensitive, so I'm trying to minimise the (significant) impact of dynamic linking.

I have changed the default visibility to hidden (`-fvisibility=hidden`) in the C/C++ compilation. I am also using `-mcmodel=large`. These have improved the performance significantly. As this is a huge project it's not quite feasible to affect project wide interface changes.

My issue is with the unit tests. The unit tests are linked against the same code and I would rather link them dynamically, as this is supposed to be one of the main benefits of the transition. However, the unit tests link against symbols in the library that are hidden.

**Functions**
I rename the functions in the library using `objcopy`. I create assembly stubs with default visibility that jump directly to the hidden symbols. I have two libraries: one for tests and one for production but they are both produced from the same object files, the test library has the additional stubs file.

**Variables**
I cannot use stubs as these are addresses indirection in the GOT table, if I understand correctly, so no code is executed. The variables issue is the lesser evil, as there are few references to global variables, so it's possible to make them visible surgically.

**Class Virtual Tables**
The class virtual tables are weak objects. Again, if I understand correctly, I cannot use the stubs method as they're not callable. I need some way to rebind them and make them visible, otherwise I need to rollback almost all the performance improvements, or recompile all the code for tests.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: make unit tests independent from the way main projects links with other projects.

Comment: By "static compilation" you mean that all the source files are compiled into final executable/library using a single stage? If your software is so performance sensitive, stay with static compilation, use (and prepare for) `-flto` and have performance. Compile unit tests as separate programs in separate stages with separate object files, so you can check various compilers and compiler/optimization options for each unit test. The think is, the source code may differ if the compiler knows when as symbol is hidden or exported (unless `-fwhole-program`).

Comment: Can you trade `-fvisibility=hidden` to `-fno-semantic-interposition`? This should keep all symbols exported but would allow compiler to optimize as agressively as in `-fvisibility=hidden` case.

Comment: VTT - Thanks, but the problem is not that by the time I link the symbols are not visible.

Comment: YUGR - -fno-semantic-interposition sound like exactly what I need. Currently we're using GCC 4.7 so we would need to upgrade but I'll see it if helps.

Comment: Kamil - currently, unless I can work some magic and gain some performance elsewhere, the production indeed stays with the static. After much work we've managed to bring it down to 10% hit for the critical path, but it's still too much. There're benefits we're missing like patching the system without replacing the whole system, using separate modules and the security of PIC code, but the 10% is too much.

Comment: @YuvGM it's been a while but if it's still relevant - is it ok to modify object files instead of final executable/shlibs? If yes, there might be a solution.

Comment: Nope, I can't change the object files but I would still be interested in the solution. The project itself sort of fizzled. It has become too complex because I couldn't find any simple solution to hybrid compilations but mainly because performance suffered a big hit (about 5-10%), so we couldn't use the dynamic version for production.